# How to implement navigation among UIView without a UINavigationController in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I have a app in which all views have an header view. The header view has to be at the top. Below the header view I need a navigation view. Unfortunately from some posts I realized that one cannot reduce the size of a `UINavigationController`.

[image]

The are where you see "Title" is where I want my navigation Bar and I want to push and pop views in the area where you see the `UITableView`.

Is there any way I can implement that without the `UINavigationController`?

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since iOS 5, you can use [Container View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html).

You'd have your regular controller, with the header and below it you'd embed an `UINavigationController`.

You can read more about it on [objc.io #1](http://www.objc.io/issue-1/containment-view-controller.html).